# How do I find the cumulative distribution function of the maximum of a random number of I.I.D variables?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The question is as follows.

Let $Y = \text{ max } \{ X_{1}, X_{2}, X_{3} \ldots X_{N} \}$

Where $X_{i} \sim U(0,1)$ and $ N \sim Po(\lambda)$

Determine $F_{Y}(y) \text{ and } f_{Y}(y) $

So far I have done the following.

$F_{Y}(y) = 0 \text{ if } y <0 \text{ and } 1 \text { if } y> 1$

For $0 < y < 1$,  $F_{Y}(y) = P[Y < y] = P[X_{1}+X_{2}+X_{3} + \ldots 
+ X_{n} < ny]$

$ \psi_{X_{1}+X_{2}+X_{3}+\ldots + X_{n}}(t) = \psi_{N}(\ln(\psi_{X_{i}}(t))$

$\psi_{N} = e^{\lambda(e^{t}-1)} \; \psi_{X_{i}} = \frac{e^{1}-1}{t} \text{ so } \psi_N(\ln(\psi_{X_{i}})) = e^{\lambda(\frac{e^t-1}{t}-1)}$

But from this point I am stuck.

Comment: "$P[Y < y] = P[X_{1}+X_{2}+X_{3} + \ldots 
+ X_{n} < ny]$" Huh? Why? Recall that $Y$ is a maximum, not a sum.

Comment: $ {X_{i}}  \sim U(0,1) $ so if $X_{max} < y$ then every $ X_{i} < y$ Thus $X_{1}+X_{2}+X_{3} + \ldots + X_{n} < y+y+y + \ldots y = n*y$  This is mostly to be able to use the moment generating function.

Comment: And it is abandoning every hope of an exact solution since $Y<y$ implies $S_n<ny$ but $S_n<ny$ does not imply $Y<y$.

Comment: Ok. So what would you suggest as an alternative?

Comment: I would suggest to treat the maximum as a maximum, not as a sum... For example, if $M_n=\max(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n)$ then $P(M_n<y)=P(X<y)^n$ for every $n$ (even for $n=0$). Now use this to compute $P(Y<y)$ where $Y=\max(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_N)$ (note the typo in your question), *adding the hypothesis that $N$ is independent of the sequence $(X_n)$* (otherwise the exercise is not doable).

Comment: @Maths For any *fixed* integer $n$, $$\Pr[\max_{1\leq i\leq n} X_i < y] = \Pr[\forall 1\leq i\leq n,\ X_i < y] = \Pr[\bigcap_{i=1}^n \{X_i < y\}] =  \prod_{i=1}^n \Pr[X_i < y]$$ (the last by independence) (edited to take Did's comment below into account)

Comment: @ClementC. But $N$...

Comment: Can you edit the question? It seems that $Y$ is a function of $N$, but you treat it as if it was a known integer.

Comment: @Did Oh, true. I read too fast, and of course treated $N$ as a constant.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Law of Total Probability, mutual independence of $N$ and all $X_\star$, and identical distribution of all $X_\star$.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(Y\leqslant y) &= \mathsf P\Bigl(\max\bigl\{X_k:k\in\{1..N\}\bigr\}\leqslant y\Bigr) \\[1ex] &= \mathsf P(N=0)+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathsf P(N=n)~\mathsf P\Bigl(\max\bigl\{X_k:k\in\{1..n\}\bigr\}\leqslant y\Bigm\vert N=n\Bigr) \\[1ex] &= \mathsf P(N=0)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathsf P(N=n)\prod_{k=1}^n\mathsf P(X_k\leqslant y) \\[1ex] &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathsf P(N=n)~\mathsf P(X_1\leqslant y)^n\\[1ex] & ~~~~\vdots \end{align}$$

Substitute the relevant pmf and CDF functions, then simplify. (HINT: use a well know Taylor Series).

Answer (score 1):

It's quite obvious that $Y \mid N$ is a beta distribution; i.e., $$F_{Y \mid N}(y) = \Pr[Y \le y \mid N] = y^{N}, \quad 0 \le y \le 1.$$  Then it is trivial to see that if $N \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)$, we have the unconditional CDF of $Y$ $$F_Y(y) = \Pr[Y \le y] = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \Pr[Y \le y \mid N = n]\Pr[N = n] = \sum_{n=0}^\infty y^n e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^n}{n!} = e^{(y-1)\lambda}.$$  Note however that there is a subtlety here: although the support of $Y$ is on $[0,1]$, we have $F_Y(0) = e^{-\lambda} > 0$.  This means that the unconditional distribution of $Y$ is not fully continuous; there is a discrete probability mass at $Y = 0$, with probability $\Pr[Y = 0] = e^{-\lambda}$.  This is because $Y = 0$ with positive probability when $N = 0$ (there are no $X_i$s to maximize!), but if $N > 0$, then $Y$ has a continuous probability density, being the maximum of a nonzero number of continuous uniform distributions.